# Adding link / image to Trello card

Tags: trello

I am new to Trello, and I am really wanting a way to add a link to a webpage, but instead of renaming it, would like to use an image that you could click to go to that web page.

This is not for a business, it is simply for my child who has dyslexia and has difficulty staying organized, and needs a simple way to access her school assignments from the schools more complicated websites.   I am creating cards for each class, and using images for ‘check grades here’, ‘daily assignments here’, ‘teachers YouTube video here’, etc.    It would be nice to just click on the images on the front of the cards to go straight to these sites without having to ‘open or turn over’ the card and have to scroll down for the link.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See https://blog.trello.com/card-cover-images-and-drag-and-drop-attachments; you can add cover images to a card that will act like an image to represent the card.

> Now you can add an image to the front of a card, too. The last uploaded image will be the default, but you can select a cover from the back of the card.
>   Your boards will look the same, but new uploaded images will be used as covers from now on.

It will solve half of your requirement, honestly. Clicking the cover image will not open the link (as you requested), but 'just' open the card (which is standard behavior and will likely not change). But if you're always including just the link of the destination in the Description of the card, your child might be able to learn to select that link. Hope this helps.